# is it best practice to define vars first before using them inside a begin block?

Tags: ruby

```
foo = ''
begin
  foo = 'hi there'
rescue
end
puts foo
```

if I don't delcare foo = '' at the top before the begin it still works. But I see a lot of people do this. And it feels better. But is it best practice?

Comment: My understanding is that a variable should be declared closely to its implementation. This is to avoid having to search around and go through a rabbit hole of code. For example if you declare one at the top of a code file and don't actually use it for a few pages, this can cause inefficient work. It may be a case of min/maxing your productivity but I do believe it makes a difference in the long run.

Comment: This "works," but (supposing there was some error that was rescued) what if the last line was `puts foo.upcase`? You would get a NoMethodError because `foo` would be `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part paranoia, and part clarity. In this trivial example there's unlikely to be an issue, but what if you had this?

```
begin
  foo = complicated_method_call(with: lots_of_arguments, and: another_call(with: args))
rescue
end
```

A whole bunch of stuff could go wrong there, and if that's the case you end up with `foo` being `nil`.

Now, using a blind `rescue` is generally bad form, you ideally want to scope down to just the ones your code might trigger.

Remember Ruby variables are defined at the method level, any instance of them in the method makes them defined, but they will have a default of `nil` which can be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, for Ruby the variable exists whenever you assign a value/object to it, making it a weakly/loosely-typed (as opposed to "strongly typed") language. Why? The focus of the language's designer was simplicity and easy of use -- see the statement in the manual :). Remember also that there isn't a need to write 'return' inside methods to return values nor write parenthesis when calling functions if there isn't confusion. Why? Simplicity, ease of use. Hard to tell if these things are better or not as a general answer. Do we have to rely always upon the compiler checks? Are we pro? Really? But generally speaking, we can hardly find ruby programmers declaring variables always unless instance/global ones, and at the end we'll getting ourselves rushing in the mainstream. Yay! General answer to determine the type of a variable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test Have fun!